# Group function by two variables on data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My data looks something like this

```
students<-data.table(studid=c(1:6) ,FACULTY= c("IT","SCIENCE", "LAW","IT","IT","IT"), 
                 SEX=c("Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Male"), WAM=c(65,35,98,55,20,80))

studid   FACULTY    SEX      AVE_MARK (WAM)
1        IT         Male     65
2        SCIENCE    Male     35
3        LAW        Male     98
4        IT         Female   55
5        IT         Female   20
6        IT         Male     80
```

I have used the following code to calculate the averages

```
degrees[, mean(WAM, na.rm=T),by=FACULTY][order(-V1)]
```

So my headings are

```
FACULTY    VI     
IT         65     
LAW        50
```

etc

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to break this up by sex also

```
FACULTY    VI     VI
           Male   Female
IT         65     11
LAW        50     11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
dcast.data.table(students, FACULTY~SEX, fun.aggregate=mean, na.rm=TRUE,
                   value.var='WAM')
#    FACULTY Female Male
#1:      IT   37.5 72.5
#2:     LAW    NaN 98.0
#3: SCIENCE    NaN 35.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you definitely need it in cross tabular format? If so, akrun's answer is the way to go.

Otherwise, here they are stacked:

```
> students[, mean(WAM, na.rm=T),by=c('FACULTY','SEX')]
   FACULTY    SEX   V1
1:      IT   Male 72.5
2: SCIENCE   Male 35.0
3:     LAW   Male 98.0
4:      IT Female 37.5
```

Comment: In this case I will need to read it into a written report so will need cross tabs.